# Windows batch: Unicode parameters for (robo) copy command

Tags: windows, unicode, batch-file, filenames

I need to copy multiple files in a single batch file. The files have Unicode names that map to different codepages.

**Example:**

```
set ArabicFile=ڊڌڵڲڛشس
set CyrillicFile=щЖЛдЉи
set GermanFile=Bücher

copy %ArabicFile% SomePlaceElse
copy %CyrillicFile% SomePlaceElse
copy %GermanFile% SomePlaceElse
```

**Problem:** Batch files cannot be Unicode.

**Question:** How can I write the Unicode file names to the batch file so that the copy command recognizes them?

**Notes:**

I do not care how the file names are displayed.
Actually the batch file does much more than just copy these files, I just simplified the description to make the problem clearer.

**Correct batch file:**

With Arnout's answer I modified my batch file as follows. It now works correctly without requiring a font change (which would be messy, as Arnout commented).

```
@echo off

chcp 65001

set ArabicFolder=ڊڌڵڲڛشس
set CyrillicFolder=щЖЛдЉи
set GermanFolder=Bücher

robocopy /e d:\temp\test\%ArabicFolder% d:\temp\test2\%ArabicFolder% /log:copy.log
robocopy /e d:\temp\test\%CyrillicFolder% d:\temp\test2\%CyrillicFolder% /log+:copy.log
robocopy /e d:\temp\test\%GermanFolder% d:\temp\test2\%GermanFolder% /log+:copy.log
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If

- I add `CHCP 65001` as the first line of your batch file,
- save the file as UTF-8 without BOM, and
- set my console font to something else than "Raster Fonts" (on my Win7 box I can choose Consolas or Lucida Console),

it works. Simple, no? :-)

(The font change is actually not necessary, provided you're not writing non-ASCII output to the console.)

Comment: The font change *can* be necessary if you intend to use command output that may contain Unicode ;)

Comment: Umm, yeah, that's what I meant with "provided you're not writing non-ASCII output to the console"...

Comment: Cool, this works ;-) Only gotcha: how do I set the font from within a batch file? The batch file is to run on multiple computers and I cannot reconfigure them prior to running my script. And the font change is required - if I do not change the font, the set commands fail.

Comment: Would adding an `ECHO OFF` do the trick, or do you depend on being able to see (some of) the output in the console window? You might be able to specify the font by importing a .REG with some settings under HKCU\Console, but that's pretty ugly and probably not very robust. (You would have to do that from another .CMD script, of course.)

Comment: On my Win7 64bit machine `CHCP` was case sensitive and I had to write the command in lower case. Otherwise the command was not recognized.

Comment: This doesn't work for my, and I need a list of all the individual folders and subfolders on my file server (more than 95000), with almost 9000 failing because of the accents. 

Funny thing is I switch to Robocopy from Powershell as I've as well problems with long paths. So kind of desperate by now...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not certain, but I think the short (8.3) filename will be ASCII, so you could refer to it that way? You can find out the short filename with `dir /X` .

Comment: Good thinking! It cannot use your solution in my case, though, because the batch file needs to run on multiple systems and the short names may differ between the computers (for example when the order in which files were created was not identical).

Comment: Short file name generation can be disabled, so you should in no case rely on them.

Answer (score 0):

I want to create a batch file (e.g. `RunThis.bat`) which creates directories of names that can be Russians or others.

Example:
When DOS Windows is open with prompt:

```
D:\>md "Russia - Шпионка"
```

This work in command like and the name appear correctly.

But if I try that using Notepad and save in `ANSII`, I can’t.
So if I use again Notepad and save in UTF-8, it will work but with garbage characters.

RunThis.bat (Notepad save UTF-8), give garbage characters.

```
chcp 65001
set fn14="Russia - Шпионка"
md %fn14%
```

The problem with notepad it uses UTF-8 **with** BOM.

To save the .bat using UTF-8 **without** BOM we must use editor like Notepad++.

RunThis.bat (Notepad++ save UTF-8 – **no BOM**)

```
chcp 65001
set fn14="Russia - Шпионка"
md %fn14%
```

This time its work perfectly when we run “`RunThis.bat`” directly from `explorer.exe`