# International characters in a batch file

Tags: windows, unicode, batch-file, cmd, ascii

Hey, I'm having some problems writing a batch file where I need to specify some file paths containing international characters (the norwegian letter 'ø' to be exact).

For example, the filename `axporteføljedb.vbp` (which looks normal in notepad) turns into `axportef°ljedb.vbp` on the command line, which the system then goes on to complain about not finding.

Any suggestions?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4193413/windows-batch-unicode-parameters-for-robo-copy-command addresses a similar issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will work if you save your batch file as ANSI with a Norwegian character set (with Notepad++ for example). Then, in the cmd, when you want to run your batch file, first change the code page to something that supports Norwegian: chcp 1252 (in the console).

Comment: Actually, it worked when I put "chcp 1252" at the top of the batch file. And I didn't have to use anything but normal Notepad.

Comment: I guess it worked with Notepad because you already had your default character set set to something Norwegian, or i might be wrong, i don't use Notepad that much nowadays. Anyway, good you got it work.

Comment: To clarify here: The console by default uses the OEM character set (CP437 or CP850 most likely) which is *not* the system's legacy encoding (which is CP1252 for most Western locales). This has historic reasons and is unfortunate and sadly with batch files the usual advice (»Use Unicode, damnit!«) isn't very helpful as you can quickly run into trouble with `chcp 65001`. Another note of caution: Remember that a `chcp` even inside a batch will persist after it's done. So if you still need the console, reset the code page to its old value (you can cache it at the start).