# How to write non-English characters in cmd

Tags: batch-file

I want to get a list of my files and save it to a txt file but my file's name have non-English characters like an Arabic file name and cmd doesn't support my files name and `cmd` saves my files name in the list like this: `???????.png`

My code is:

```
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
For /r .  %%g in (*.png *.jpg) do echo %%~nxg >>listfile.txt`
```

Comment: A few questions. What is your default code page?  What program are you using to view the text file?

Comment: try `chcp 65001` for UTF-8 codepage

Comment: Maybe it could help to run the batch file in a command prompt with Unicode output opened by: [`cmd`](http://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html)`/U` (perhaps even in combination with the [`chcp`](http://ss64.com/nt/chcp.html) command)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows batch: Unicode parameters for (robo) copy command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4193413/windows-batch-unicode-parameters-for-robo-copy-command)

Comment: Take a look at this ==> [How to make cmd and batch script display correctly arabic characters?](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=8388)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`chcp` is a command that ***ch**anges* the ***c**ode **p**age*.

You could just use:

```
chcp 65001
```

which is the UTF-8 code page and UTF-8 is probably the most common Unicode, encoding. UTF-8 uses 2 bytes per Arabic character.

Answer (score 1):

I found [this](https://superuser.com/questions/625866/cmd-how-to-use-non-english-characters?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) on [superuser.com](https://superuser.com/questions/625866/cmd-how-to-use-non-english-characters?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa), might be of use.
Basically, you set the encoding of the CMD window to a specific charset.

Try `chcp 1256`

Comment: don't use ANSI codepages anymore. better use Unicode